# Ищу компонент для .NET WinForms

Tags: winforms, .net

Нужен компонент для навигации, требуется работа в 4-х направлениях.
Такой компонент используется в Google Maps. Подскажите библиотеку или хотя бы категорию. Вот пример:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать так. Создать PictureBox с таким битмапом, как на картинке. По умолчанию он скрыт, при активации он появляется в месте, куда наведена мышь. Для того чтобы он был прозрачным, в качестве фона следует подложить ему кусок карты, лежащий под ним (из графического контекста карты выцепить клочок под компонентом и конвертировать его в Image). Запоминаем MousePosition. Дальше запускаем таймер, который сравнивает текущее положение курсора с исходным, перемещает карту вдоль линии, соединяющей положения курсора и подменяет фон PictureBox'а на новый клочок карты, под ним оказавшийся.

Comment: спасибо, но у меня случай тривиальней (работы не с картой, а с вращением и перемещением объекта в пространстве), хочется что-нибудь удобное для навигации в 4-х или 8-ми направлениях

Answer (score 1):

Контрол нестандартный - таких не видел. Попробуйте поискать по категориям карт (Maps & GIS) или просто по кнопкам (Button). По картам встречаются [такие](http://gis.thinkgeo.com/T4/CSharpMap/tabid/831/Default.aspx?adcampaign=Map+Suite+Tech+Terms&leadsource=Google&adgroup=CSharp&adtype=search&keyword=cs+maps&gclid=CJ29kp_XvqYCFcKIDgodn3ozIQ) вещи, а по кнопкам - [такие](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/Free/NetOffer/) (Control Navigator).

Comment: DevExpress пробовал, ничего похожего увы там не нашлось